# Rerun Javascript in dynamically filled iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

On a page i try to fill an empty `<iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>` with the HTML code of an ajax result. That works well, except script tags in the code are not being executet, so i have to readd them to the iframe's page:

```
$.post('page.php', function(code) {

    $("#myFrame").contents().find("html").get(0).innerHTML = code;

    $("#myFrame").contents().find("script").each(function() {

        $old_script = $(this);
        $frame = document.getElementById("myFrame");

        $new_script = $frame.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
        $new_script.type = "text/javascript";
        $new_script.src = $old_script.attr("src");

        $old_script.remove();
        $frame.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild($new_script);

    });

});
```

That works basically, but the document seems to load the Javascript files in a different order. There are 3 js files to load: jquery.min.js, a jquery plugin and a main.js file to control the bahavior inside the iframe:

```
// main.js:

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("frame document loaded");
    // call the jquery plugins etc...
});
```

The page alerts me "frame document loaded", but cannot execute the jquery plugins. Double-checked the script paths, but they're right. Seems that the jquery.min.js and main.js are loaded before the plugin files.

How could i achieve to load the javascript files one by one as specified originally in the code returned by the ajax request?

**EDIT:** Forgot to say that sometimes everything works well and the javascript seems to be loaded correctly. On reload it breaks again.

Comment: Are they being detected in the right order or not?

Comment: I'm not sure. But if jquery is loaded ($(document).ready() can be executed) and the main.js file is also loaded, but the jquery plugin cannot be called, i think it's not really loaded in the right order..